# latex newcommand in doxgygen html output

Tags: latex, doxygen, mathjax

I followed the doxygen manual and some other questions here on stack overflow and I managed to get doxygen to create a pdf out of my code. I am writing a manual, have lots of equations, and want a consistent notation, so I created a latex style file. My setup in a folder `manual` is roughly like

```
html/
latex/
Doxyfile
style.sty
```

I then had to create a link in `latex/` to make it work `ln -s ../style.sty` and `style.sty` is

```
\newcommand{\cond}{\,|\,}
\newcommand\rmdx[1]{\mbox{d}#1\,}
```

and I add to `Doxyfile`

```
EXTRA_PACKAGES         = style
```

Unfortunately the html output created only contains mathjax boxes saying

```
Undefined control sequence \cond
```

while the math is fine in the pdf

Answer (score 4):

The somewhat tedious way is configure mathjax in javascript to learn the `newcommand`s like this:

Add `MATHJAX_CODEFILE = newcommands.js` to `doxyfile`.Then
create `newcommands.js` in the same directory as `doxyfile`

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    TeX: {
        Macros: {
            cond: ["{\\,|\\,}"],
            rmdx: ["{\\mbox{d}#1\\,}",1]
        }
    }
});
```

So the commands have to be duplicated to have pdf and html output but at least this works.

sources: doxygen manual on mathjax http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#config_html, mathjax manual on tex macros http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#defining-tex-macros

Comment: A proposed doxygen patch exists for this, see https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/7230. This handles the PDF case and also the MathJax case.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I'm sure it is still relevant to many doxygen users. So here is an alternative:

There is a slightly easier solution. I' am not sure if it applies to older versions of MathJax, but it does work in v2.7.
You can use `\htmlonly` and `\endhtmlonly` to achieve the same without creating an outside file like `newcommands.js`. For example:

```
\htmlonly
    \(
        \def\KK{\bf K}
        \def\uu{\bf u}
        \def\ff{\bf f}
    \)
\endhtmlonly
```

Defines 3 macros. It would be local to only one HTML file. So depending on your case, the `newcommands.js` may be easier or this one may be easier.

The [`\htmlonly` and `\endhtml` tags](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdhtmlonly) delimit text that will be placed verbatim in the html output. The [`\(` and `\)` tags](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#defining-tex-macros) delimit parts that MathJax will process.

Comment: A proposed doxygen patch exists for this, see https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/7230. This handles the PDF case and also the MathJax case.